# How to pass variable argument list in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that is always called like this:

```
old_function(sprintf("Some arbitrary data %d, %s, %f\n", $i, $s, $f));
```

Is it possible in PHP to make a function that combines these to functions for

```
new_function("Some arbitrary data %d, %s, %f\n", $i, $s, $f);
```

In the beginning of new_function, the variable argument list of the function would have to be parsed and passed to sprintf internally:

```
function new_function( /* variable argument list */ )
{
     $string = sprintf( /* variable argument list */ );
     return old_function($string);
}
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/function.func-get-args.php) & [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) for this:

```
function new_function()
{
     // get all function arguments
     $args = func_get_args();
     // run the function "sprintf" with the given arguments
     $string = call_user_func_array("sprintf", $args);
     return old_function($string);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.6, you can try to use [Variadic Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) via `...` operator. This new feature enables native support for passing variable-length argument lists to any function.

Try something like this:

```
public function new_function(...$params) {
    $string = call_user_func_array("sprintf", $params);
    return old_function($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) method. Which can retrieve variable length arguments.

Comment: That's nice, but that does not tell me how to actually pass the arguments to sprintf